# FindRoot over a function with some constant variables

Tags: functions, equation-solving

I would like to perform the `FindRoot` command over the function `func`. Suppose:

```
func = Function[{x,y,z},{x+y+z,3x-y-0.5z}]
```

I would like to solve `func==0` over the variables `y`, `z` over a grid of inputs `x`. Since my actual `func` is more complicated, I have to resort to using `FindRoot` rather than `Solve`.

One way to do this is to execute:

```
FindRoot[func[x0,y,z], {{y, y0}, {z, z0}}]
```

where `x0` is a numeric input.

However, since my actual `y`, `z` consist of a large (and non-constant) number of variables, I wish to execute the following command:

```
FindRoot[func[x0, variables], {startingvariables}]
```

This however does not seem to work as either,

- all variables have to be specified manually, or
- the function has to be redefined

Is there a way out?

Comment: Please provide a working example, as `FindRoot[func[x0,y,z],{{y,y0},{z,z0}]` cannot work (you have one equation `func[x0,y,z] == 0`, but two unknowns, `y` and `z`).

Comment: sorry for that! The system has 3 variables and 2 equations. I set one variable as fixed, so that remain 2 eqs + 2 unknowns

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by @LLIAMnYP, `FindRoot` cannot solve one equation for two unknowns.

You may be able to use `FindInstance`

```
func = Plus;

n = 4; (* number of variables *)

var = Array[x, n];

x[1] = 5; (* fixed variable *)

ns = 4; (* number of solutions *)
```

For `Integers`

```
solnI = FindInstance[
  func @@ var == 0, Rest[var], Integers, ns]
```

> {{x[2] -> -168, x[3] -> 39, x[4] -> 124}, {x[2] -> 66, x[3] -> -17,
>   x[4] -> -54}, {x[2] -> 134, x[3] -> -43, x[4] -> -96}, {x[2] -> 199,
>   x[3] -> -43, x[4] -> -161}}

Domain can be changed to `Reals` or `Complexes` (default). Inequalities can be used to constrain the domain.